# How to update python dataframe blank row of one column with data of other column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below script, giving error:

> ValueError: cannot re-index from a duplicate axis

Code:

```
dataAll.loc[dataAll['GenderCode'] == '', 'GenderCode'] = dataAll.loc[dataAll['SEX.id'] != '', 'SEX.id']
```

In SQL I will write as:

```
update dataAll set GenderCode=SEX.id where GenderCode='' and SEX.id!=''
```

How to achieve this?

I have executed below script, but not working.

```
dataAll['GenderCode'].unique()
array(['001', '002', '003', '004', '096', '098', '', 'KN.GA'], dtype=object)
dataAll['SEX.id'].unique()
array(['001', '002', '003', '004', '096', '098', ''], dtype=object)

temp = dataAll.loc[dataAll['GenderCode'] == '']
len(temp)
>> 684090

mask = (dataAll['GenderCode'] == '') & (dataAll['SEX.id'] != '')
dataAll['GenderCode'] = np.where(mask, dataAll['SEX.id'], dataAll['GenderCode'])

temp = dataAll.loc[dataAll['GenderCode'] == '']
len(temp)
>> 684090
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need chain conditions with `&` and then set values by mask:

```
mask = (dataAll['GenderCode'] == '') & (dataAll['SEX.id'] != '')
dataAll.loc[mask, 'GenderCode'] = dataAll['SEX.id']
```

Or:

```
dataAll['GenderCode'] = np.where(mask, dataAll['SEX.id'], dataAll['GenderCode'])
```

Sample:

Data are not updated if empty both values in columns (row with `index=1`)

```
dataAll = pd.DataFrame({'GenderCode':['a','','s',''],
                        'SEX.id':['','','b','d']})

print (dataAll)
  GenderCode SEX.id
0          a       
1                  
2          s      b
3                 d

mask = (dataAll['GenderCode'] == '') & (dataAll['SEX.id'] != '')
dataAll.loc[mask, 'GenderCode'] = dataAll['SEX.id']
print (dataAll)

  GenderCode SEX.id
0          a       
1                  
2          s      b
3          d      d
```

And solution for append data if empty strings in both columns is add new condition and append new value like `no_data`:

```
m = dataAll['GenderCode'] == ''
m1 = m & (dataAll['SEX.id'] != '')
m2 =  m  & (dataAll['SEX.id'] == '')

dataAll['GenderCode'] = np.select([m1, m2], 
                                  [dataAll['SEX.id'], 'no_data'], 
                                  default=dataAll['GenderCode'])
print (dataAll)

  GenderCode SEX.id
0          a       
1    no_data       
2          s      b
3          d      d
```

Comment: I think I know what is problem - there are in both columns empty strings, so condition return False

Comment: I also add solution for your problem.